# VBA to copy/paste rows between worksheets when amount of rows always changes?

Tags: find

Using VBA I need to copy certain rows based on one column’s data, and paste into another worksheet. The trick is the amount of rows I need to copy is always changing. Using column ‘A’ the macro has to copy all rows until the phrase ‘Respondent ID’ is found. I then need it to copy all rows above that and paste into worksheet B. I found something in another macro that looks somewhat helpful, but I’m having trouble converting…

```
Sheets("WorksheetA").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
       Selection.Find(What:="Respondent ID", after:=ActiveCell, 
LookIn:=xlFormulas _
           , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
           _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       Rows(ActiveCell.Row - 1).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Rows("1:1").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
```

But this just copies one row and it only copies into the same worksheet.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works for me. If you are also trying to do this, try finding the cell with that certain value ("Respondent ID" in this case) and then either clearing content or deleting all rows UNDER that row (I went with clear contents.) You then can copy and paste remaining data.

```
`Sheets("SheetA").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
       Selection.Find(What:="Respondent ID", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
           , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Rows(ActiveCell.row + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents`
```